# Eclipse GWT java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, gwt

I now have a clean compile of my code and am using WAMPServer. However, when I try to run my code from Eclipse (Run as, GWT aplication) I get the following error in the console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.validateServletTags(DevMode.java:611)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:449)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1083)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

This is the code associated with the first line (I have not included the rest for brevity, please let me know if you need it):

```
"DevMode.java:611"

TreeLogger servletLogger =
    logger.branch(TreeLogger.DEBUG, "Validating <servlet> tags for module '" + module.getName()
        + "'", null, new InstalledHelpInfo("servletMappings.html"));
for (String servletPath : servletPaths) {
  String servletClass = module.findServletForPath(servletPath);
  assert (servletClass != null);
  // Prefix module name to convert module mapping to global mapping.
  servletPath = "/" + module.getName() + servletPath;
  if (servletValidator == null) {
    servletWriter.addMapping(servletClass, servletPath);
  } else {
    servletValidator.validate(servletLogger, servletClass, servletPath);
  }
```

This is my

```
AwardTracker.get.xml

<module>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
<entry-point class="org.AwardTracker.client.AwardTracker"/>

<!--  servelet context - path is arbitrary, but must match up with the rpc init inside java class -->
<!--  Tomcat will listen for this from the server and waits for rpc request in this context -->
<servlet class="org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection" path="/MySQLConnection" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark"/>
</module>
```

And this is my

```
web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>AwardTracker.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>

<servlet>
     <servlet-name>mySQLConnection</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>mySQLConnection</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/MySQLConnection</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

**The Answer Is:**

The WEB.XML was not in the correct order. It should have been:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<servlet>
     <servlet-name>mySQLConnection</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>mySQLConnection</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/MySQLConnection</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>AwardTracker.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>    

</web-app>
```

Thank you,

Glyn

Comment: Please mention GWT version and whether you are using gwt with external server configuration ( you are not using jetty, eh ? )

Comment: I am using the Eclipse Juno GWT plugin installed via the Eclipse update manager a few weeks ago, so it should be the latest. I am not using jetty. I am new to this and have been using examples to configure and code to this point so I am not sure if I am using an external server configuration. How do I tell please?

Comment: The answer is that the WEB.xml was not in the correct order. Please see above for the correct WEB.xml. Thanks, Glyn.

Answer (score 0):

please go to "validateServletTags(DevMode.java:611)"    and check the line. try printing all the variables.  that should tell you which is null.

Comment: The line is: if (servletValidator == null) {
        servletWriter.addMapping(servletClass, servletPath); Regards, Glyn

Comment: try printing the servletWriter  servletClass and  servletPath. in 3 System output statements.  before the condition

Comment: I can not edit the DevMode.class; it will not allow any changes. I am very new to this so sorry if I am missing something obvious. Regards, Glyn

Comment: I have been able to do a PrtScn of the page that flashes up when I run this. The message is "00:00:00:005 [WARN] Unable to process 'file:/C:/Users/Glyndwr/Eclipse/Workspace/AwardTracker/war/WEB-INF/web.xml' for servlet validation - exception: SAXPars" ... the rest is over the end of the page.

Comment: The answer is that the WEB.xml was not in the correct order. Please see above for the correct WEB.xml.